# Storing data of an alarm settings

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsuserdefaults, alarm

I am making an alarm app. Now I want to know how can I  store the alarm settings save in my app. I have a little knowledge of NSUserDefaults. My problem is that I don't know how to give a unique id to each alarm e.g. if user select the same settings for two alarm than delete  alarm one alarm  than both the alarm would be  deleted.I don't know how to use sqlite. So any suggestions or code ?? 
Thanks

Comment: Seems like a very broad question where you state you don't know about sqlite or `NSUserDefaults` and want to know some ideas for creating a unique ID for each alarm.  Not sure it belongs here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can chose system time with seconds. You can get the time on which alarm is set than make that time as a unique.

```
CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Than on that base you can save your alarm in nsuserdefaults and also check out the tuturiols for nususerdefaults it's so easy.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not for storing general data.